# Gmail - Can't forward bounced emails

Tags: gmail, forward, email-bounces

I've configured bounced/undelivered emails to come to a particular mail box. However I've set up a filter where any email sent to this mail box will be forwarded to another email address. This currently works with just a normal email and gets forwarded correctly, but with undelivered emails, it never gets forwarded at all. This is the filter I have currently

```
Matches: to:(alerts@somecompany.com.au)
Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply label "Alerts", Forward to name@somecompany.com.au, Never send it to Spam, Never mark it as important
```

This is the email that gets landed in the mailbox that we want to forward

> ---
>
> Mail Delivery System 14:53 (53 minutes ago)
>
> This is the mail system at host ***************.
>
> I'm sorry to have to inform you that your message could not be
>   delivered to one or more recipients. It's attached below.
>
> For further assistance, please send mail to postmaster.
>
> If you do so, please include this problem report. You can delete your
>   own text from the attached returned message.
>
> ---

If anyone knows how to fix this problem, your help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you ever make any progress with this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not, never addressed it for the project I was working on in the end

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [webapps.se].